# RSpec returning innaccurate time for length of run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm seeing

```
"Finished in 19641310.62 seconds"
```

When in actuality its about 70 seconds.  I'm running rspec 2.5 under spork.

Comment: Are you using time cop or otherwise stubbing/changing the date/time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw this once before when I was using TimeCop. I set the time to be in the past using TimeCop and never called return to set it back to the present time. Are you using TimeCop or do you manipulate the time in your test suite anywhere ?

You could also narrow down the problem file by calling: rspec spec/models or rspec spec/model/user_spec.rb from the command line and see which file introduces this time issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time` command if you're on a UNIX system ;)

Example : `time rspec spec/`

Comment: Heh, thanks, but I'm talking about the built in RSpec functionality that prints out the time for the spec run thats acting wonky

Comment: That may be a bug... You can report it in RSpec's bug tracker. But I showed you the command as an alternative.